# Read more, Read less Script - setting Initial div height and and another height when button is click

Tags: jquery

Good morning everyone!

I have a **read more/read less** script. The user click the read more tab and more text appears. Here is how it is set up. there is a DIV which holds all the contents, within this DIV is another DIV which also holds the additional contents. Both DIVS does not have fixed heights. I would like to set an initial height to the container DIV which is the **Content Box**, Example: An initial height of say 200px, and when read more is click, make the **Content Box** 400px.

Here is the code (html):

```
<div class="contentBox">
<p>Initial Text goes here</p>

<a class="addlTextTrigger" href="#">Read More</a>

<div class="addlTextBox">
<p>Additional Text here.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the JQuery, please not the JQuery switches styles but this is simply used to style the tab/links used for triggering the read more/read less function.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.addlTextBox').hide();
$('.addlTextBoxTrigger').toggle(function(){
$('.addlTextBox').fadeIn('fast');
$(this).text("Read Less");
},
function(){
$('.addlTextBox').hide('fast');
$(this).text("Read More");
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.addlTextBoxTrigger').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('readMoreClick');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/pwSdd/11/)

Using css classes and turning them on/off

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addlTextBox').hide();
    $(".contentBox").addClass("readLess");
    $('.addlTextTrigger').toggle(function() {
        $('.addlTextBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $(".contentBox").removeClass("readLess");
            .addClass("readMore");
        $(this).text("Read Less");
    }, function() {
        $('.addlTextBox').hide('fast');
        $(".contentBox").addClass("readLess");
            .removeClass("readMore");
        $(this).text("Read More");
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.readLess {
    height: 200px;
}

.readMore {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused. The Content Box is already a class which is assigned to the div that holds the additional content. I should have mentioned that I set the initial height to the Content Box, however, I need this height to change on the content box when the button(tab) is clicked.

Comment: @Overmars then just toggle a class that changes the height to 400.